# Robocopy not copying files in subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am having problems with robocopy for whatever reason.

I have several scripts I use daily that utilize copy, xcopy, and robocopy, and they are all working currently, except for this one. I am using the same, standard switches I use in my other scripts.

```
robocopy "K:\Some Folder" "H:\Files\1" /e /w:0 /r:2 /MIR
```

Any files directly in `K:\Some Folder` get copied. But any files in, say `K:\Some Folder\Some Subfolder` do *not* get copied. I looked this up and using either /s or /e should copy all files in sub-directories as well. Why isn't it? If I pause the script, it says "*Extra Files" in some places - that might have something to do with it.

Previously I was using these switches, but it still didn't work after simplifying:

```
 /e /w:0 /r:2 /XO /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np
```

Comment: `/mir` switch includes `/e` and `/purge` so `*Extra File` is logged when a file is being deleted from destination, in your case - from `H:\Files\1` folder. Your command looks good to me, it works for me anywa. I can't think of anything else than robocopy having no read access to the subfolders of your source, `K:\ some folder`. If you're using NTFS, check if all subfolders inherit permissions from source folder. If this is a network drive - check share read rights.

Comment: @Kitet K:\ is a WebDav share. H:\ is a local network share on an in-house file server. I keep files in the WebDav share so I can access them outside of the building, but for complicated reasons, even though I can map K:\, I need  them to also be available on local network storage. Yes, I have permissions to everything and can do this graphically, but I do this at logon/logoff via script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Problem:*** Any files directly in `K:\Some Folder` get copied. But any files in `K:\Some Folder\Some Subfolder` do not get copied.

The solution is to **not** use robocopy at all, but use **xcopy**.

Instead of:

```
robocopy "K:\Some Folder" "H:\Files\1" /e /w:0 /r:2 /MIR
```

this should be used instead:

```
xcopy "K:\Some Folder" "H:\Files\1" /c /s /e /y
```

I don't know why **robocopy** didn't work, but **xcopy** with these switches does what needs to be done, quickly and efficiently.

Comment: "Xcopy has been deprecated under Vista and Windows 2008, this means that while still available now it might disappear in a future OS release. To ensure your scripts are 'future proof' use other tools (such as Robocopy) instead of xcopy. " according to https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Answer (score 4):

There's a `/S` option in `robocopy`, too. (See [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).) Also a `/E` that is like `/S`, but additionally forces empty folders to be copied.

| Flag | Behavior |
| --- | --- |
| `/S` | Copy **S**ubfolders |
| `/E` | Copy subfolders, including **E**mpty subfolders |

Supposedly, `/MIR` ***implies*** `/E`…

| Flag | Behavior |
| --- | --- |
| `/MIR` | **MIR**ror a directory tree—equivalent to `/PURGE` plus all subfolders (`/E`) |

…but I have not found this to be empirically true. **You should include the `/E` or `/S` option explicitly.**

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `/b` (Backup mode) switch works for me.  Even though it appeared that I had the proper permissions to copy, `robocopy` seemed to disagree. `/b` fixed that issue.